# Does the "Groups for Business" service have a fee if you are already an Apps For Business customer?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-email, google-apps-for-work

Is there a fee to enable "Groups for Business" if you already have a Google Apps for Business domain, or is it simply a service that can be turned on or off?

Answer (score 3):

Groups for Business is part of Google apps, if you have Google apps for Business it's a [service you can turn on](https://support.google.com/a/answer/167096?hl=en)